# Retrieve revision text through Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm playing with getting the revision history of a document through Google Apps Script and I'm looking for some advice on how to programmatically access the content of the revision.

Using the Drive API, I can access an array of revisions on the document and iterate based on user. The returned object does not include the *content* of the revision, just an ID. But, you can get a download URL for various content types (pdf, plaintext, etc).

I'd like to retrieve a download URL using `UrlFetchApp` and get that content to append to a document. The problem is that the fetch app returns the entire document markup (HTML and CSS) and I'd only like the content of the file.

**Script**

```js
function revisionHistoryLite() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var eds = doc.getEditors();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var revs = Drive.Revisions.list(doc.getId())

  var editsList = [];

  for(var i=0; i<revs.items.length; i++) {
    var revision = revs.items[i];
    editsList.push([revision.id, revision.kind, revision.modifiedDate, revision.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress]);

    if(revision.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress == "bbennett@elkhart.k12.in.us") {
      var revUrl = Drive.Revisions.get(doc.getId(), revision.id).exportLinks["text/plain"];

      // revUrl returns https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=docIdString&revision=1&exportFormat=txt

      var revString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(revUrl, { contentType: "text/plain",  }).getContentText();
      Logger.log(revString); // Contains full HTTP markup

      // Append the body contents to a temporary document for further processing
      // var tempDoc = DocumentApp.create("Temp").getBody().appendParagraph(revString);


    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it downloads files from exportLinks using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`, the authorization is required. So please modify your script as follows.

#### From :

```
var revUrl = Drive.Revisions.get(doc.getId(), revision.id).exportLinks["text/plain"];
var revString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(revUrl, { contentType: "text/plain",  }).getContentText();
```

#### To :

```
var revUrl = Drive.Revisions.get(doc.getId(), revision.id).exportLinks["text/plain"]  + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var revString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(revUrl).getContentText();
```

By this, you can download text data from the revision data.

### Edit :

```
function revisionHistoryLite() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var eds = doc.getEditors();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var revs = Drive.Revisions.list(doc.getId())
  var editsList = [];
  for(var i=0; i<revs.items.length; i++) {
    var revision = revs.items[i];
    editsList.push([revision.id, revision.kind, revision.modifiedDate, revision.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress]);
    if(revision.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress == "### mail address ###") {
      var revUrl = Drive.Revisions.get(doc.getId(), revision.id).exportLinks["text/plain"]  + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var revString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(revUrl).getContentText();
      Logger.log(revString); // Contains full HTTP markup
    }
  }
}
```

#### Updated: February 7, 2020

From January, 2020, the access token cannot be used with the query parameter like `access_token=###`. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) So please use the access token to the request header instead of the query parameter. It's as follows.

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
```

Comment: I had authorized already, so that wasn't the issue. Still returns full HTML markup rather than the plaintext file that downloads.

Comment: @Brian Bennett In my environment, I confirmed that the plaintext from revision data can be retrieved using my answer. So can you show me your most current script?

Comment: I'll check it again - did you just log `revString` to see the content?

Comment: Ah, it was the underscore. Got it! Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Brian Bennett Welcome. Thank you, too.